# Tell Dynamic Linker To Call My Function Instead of Function In Another Shared Library

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I have a closed source library that has a function that I need to call via dlsym (it's part of a driver I'm writing and the only way to control the hardware is to call functions in this closed source library) and it references another function in another library which loads configuration information.  Is it possible to have the function I call in the library call my own function to load the configuration information?  Here's a code illustration of what I'm trying to do (I skipped the declaration of variables for brevity):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  library = dlopen("/usr/local/lib/libuLinux_hal.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  func_point = dlsym(library, "ec_sys_set_fan_speed");
  func_point(arg1, arg2); // Makes a call to Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int and does other stuff
}

int Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int(int arg)
{
  // Do stuff

  return 0;
}
```

The ec_sys_set_fan_speed function in the libuLinux_hal.so library calls a function called Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int (that is located in another library).  I would like to somehow tell the dynamic linker to instead call my own Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int function in my program.  Is this possible?

Edit: based on Employed Russian's answer I modified my compile statement to be:

```
cc -o qnap-ec qnap-ec-helper.c -Wall -O2 -ldl -Wl,--export-dynamic-symbol=Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int
```

however I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol xport-dynamic-symbol=Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int; defaulting to 00000000000011c0
```

In case it's helpful my ld version information is

```
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Yes.

You need to do *two* things to make this work:

1. define `Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int()` function in your main program (you are already doing that) and
2. make that function *exported* in the dynamic symbol table (visible in the output from `nm -D a.out | grep ' Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int$'`).

You are *probably* missing step 2.

To accomplish step 2, use `-Wl,--export-dynamic` flag when linking the main executable.

If your linker supports `--export-dynamic-symbol` flag, a better solution is to use `-Wl,--export-dynamic-symbol,Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int`.

Comment: Using -export-dynamic works, however, when I use -export-dynamic-symbol,Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int I get the following linker error: cannot find entry symbol xport-dynamic-symbol,Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int; defaulting to 00000000000011c0

Comment: @HarryMuscle You appear to have missed the `-Wl,` in front of `--export-dynamic-symbol`.

Comment: Sorry, I removed that from my comment for brevity, the full linker flag is exactly like you mentioned: -Wl,--export-dynamic-symbol,Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int

Comment: @HarryMuscle I am not sure I believe you. Please edit your question with the _exact_ command and the _exact_ error output. Also please show the output from `ld --version`.

Comment: As requested I added the details to my original question.

Comment: @HarryMuscle I can't reproduce your failure, using your _exact_ command. I suspect you aren't _actually_ using `--` (minus minus). The failure is consistent with having a single `-`, and if I use `-Wl,-export-dynamic-symbol=Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int`, I get your exact error). Maybe use `-Wl,--export-dynamic-symbol=Ini_Conf_Get_Field_Int,-v` to see what arguments are actually passed to the linker. Do you have some kind of wrapper around your `cc` ?

Comment: You were right about missing the second dash.  However, with -- in front of export-dynamic-symbol I get this error now: /usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--export-dynamic-symbol'

Comment: @HarryMuscle So your `ld` doesn't support this flag. The flag was added in commit 37a141bfed4d in 2020-06-03, and was included in the binutils `2.35` release. Get a newer linker, or use `--export-dynamic`.

Comment: @HarryMuscle Also try not to mislead next time -- I asked for your _exact_ command, and you pasted the one with two dashes, while _actually_ using one dash.

Comment: There was no misleading, just a typing error ... I'm running the compiling commands on one machine while accessing StackOverflow on another so it was simply a transcribing error, no copy/paste was actually involved.